# How to filter table via value type in cell vba

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I want to filter table on another sheet based on single cell value from the first one

Hi, during preparation of new report i faced such problem: i tried filter table on another sheet based on single cell value from the first one. Code which i wrote seems working but insteed of showing demanded results it highlight only empty rows. If i insteed of using string, put the date directly inside the code everything looks fine but alas it is not what i'm lookin for. Any advice?

```
Sub Makro3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim mySearch As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set ws = Arkusz6
    Set sht = Arkusz1
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("ineffective")
    'Set tbl = ws.Range("A4:E31")
    mySearch = sht.Range("B2").Value

    'tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="28.06.2019", Operator:=xlAnd
    'tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & TextBox1.Text & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    'tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Text & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValue
    'tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can auto-filter a table for a date value, based on the value of a cell on another sheet.  In the example below, the dates are in column 2 of the table.

```
Sub FilterTable()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet 'sheet with the table
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet 'sheet with the search parameter
    Dim tbl As ListObject 'table object
    Dim mySearch As Variant 'or Dim as Date; cell with the search parameter

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Filter Table by Type")
    Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("t_Data")
    mySearch = ws2.Range("A1").Value
    Debug.Print "mySearch = " & mySearch


    With tbl.Range

        '~~> Show all records
        .AutoFilter Field:=2

        If IsDate(mySearch) Then

            .AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
            Criteria1:=mySearch

        Else

            .AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
            Criteria1:=DateSerial(Year(mySearch), Month(mySearch), Day(mySearch))

        End If

    End With


    '~~> Release the variables from memory
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing
    mySearch = vbNull

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for answer, in the mean time i  solve this issue myself (below working cde - it was a matter of two things. 1. I forgot to put lDate = mySearch after mySearch = sht.Range("B2") so lDate was empty... i replaced it in the correct order and 2. The date format must be the same as inf the host system)  i"ll check your solution as well :)